# .htaccess rewrite is resulting in 404

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have my .htaccess set up to rewrite 'friendly URLs' - the first is working perfectly and rewrites as it should, however the second, which is written in exactly the same way does not work and results in a 404. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

The following rewrites correctly to mysite.com/1:

```
# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of DYHAMB
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for DYHAMB
RewriteRule ^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1&podcast=DYHAMB [L,QSA]
# External redirect for DYHAMB
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episode\.php\?episode=(\d+)\&podcast\=DYHAMB [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

However this should rewrite to mysite.com/new/1 but actually returns 404:

```
# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of new
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for new
RewriteRule ^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1&podcast=new [L,QSA]
# External redirect for new
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episode\.php\?episode=(\d+)\&podcast\=new [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match the "new" part of the redirected URI:

```
RewriteRule ^new/(0|[1-9]\d{0,2})$ /episode.php?episode=$1&podcast=new [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've made the amendment as you suggested which of course makes perfect sense, however I'm still getting a 404. Now I'm really unsure what I'm missing.